# Chart.js jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the fiddle i tried 
http://jsfiddle.net/7ktug/134/

I tried with lovely plugin of `chart.js`. In that `data` attribute i tried this way

```
data: [10,15,16,100]
```

It working perfect when i tried with this way

```
<div id="samplevalue" style="display:none">10,15,16,100</div>
```

**js**

```
var n = jQuery("#samplevalue").text();       
var m = jQuery("#newvalue").text();
alert(n);
alert(m);
var barChartData = {
            labels: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    scaleSteps: 100,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    barShowStroke: false,
                    data: [n]
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    scaleSteps: 100,
                    barShowStroke: false,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    data: [m]
                }
            ]

        }
```

I put this way 
as
`data[n]` as well as `data[m]` but it not working fine.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [split the text data into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) in each case. Adding square brackets around the variable name won't work. Try:

```
data: n.split(',')
```

and

```
data: m.split(',')
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy I tried your suggestion it working but for value containing 100 also but it won't visible in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ktug/138/

Comment: @User, not quite sure I follow. Is it working how you wanted?

Comment: Ok Thanks for your information mate. +1 Much appreciate your timely help